# function.call() return global this

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am trying to bind the user object as this and default time as the first parameter using `function.call` method

```js
let user = {
  name:'rifat',
  txt (time, msg){
    console.log('['+time+ '] '+ this.name+ ' : '+ msg);
  }
}


function bind(func, ...fArgs){
  return function(...args){
    return func.call(this, ...fArgs, ...args);
  };
}

let txt =  bind(user.txt, new Date().getHours()+':' +new Date().getMinutes() );

txt('hey!');
```

why does this code return undefined name. Running in node 10.16.0.0

```sh
[18:21] undefined : hey!
```

Comment: You're binding whatever `this` is inside `bind() { ... }`, which is `undefined`/`window`.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `bind` manually?

Comment: Also what you are trying to do can be done like so: 
`function bind(...args){
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(...args)
}`

Comment: Maybe, You can use the standard syntax for `.call` or `.apply` as it takes the `this` as the first argument, you can do the same with your `bind` function. take the `user` as first argument.

Comment: You can also do this: 
`let bind = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind)`;

Comment: i want to omit the context and jump to arguments while calling bind, with built in bind I will have to specify this every time .  this is just the regular bind without the first parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok everyone, thank you for your suggestions and comments. I think I found what I did wrong.

**I was storing the return of the bind function in txt variable, which loses `this`.** What I had to do was replacing the `user.txt` with the return function or store it in another `user` object value like `user.txtBound`

the correct version of the code would be

```js
let user = {
  name:'rifat',
  txt (time, msg){
    console.log('['+time+ '] '+ this.name+ ' : '+ msg);
  }
}


function bind(func, ...fArgs){
  return function(...args){
    return func.call(this, ...fArgs, ...args); // here 'this' will be determined 
                                                //when the returned function executes
  };
}

user.txt =  bind(user.txt, new Date().getHours()+':' +new Date().getMinutes() ); 
// storing the returned function as a object property

user.txt('hey!'); //this works fine
```

this one just works fine.

Sorry everyone for the trouble, I was experimenting :)

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is actually supported by the native `bind` itself.

```
let user = {
  name:'rifat',
  txt (time, msg){
    console.log('['+time+ '] '+ this.name+ ' : '+ msg);
  }
}

let txt =  user.txt.bind(user, new Date().getHours()+':' +new Date().getMinutes());

txt('hey!');
```

Output:

```
[18:11] rifat : hey!
```

You can check out more about partial functions [here](https://javascript.info/bind#partial-functions)